# Eclipse XML Schema Editor cannot handle links during validation?

Tags: eclipse, xsd, hyperlink, xsd-validation

I have modules with XSD-files and want to include the XSD of module-A (e.g. a.xsd) at module-B (e.g. b.xsd) using no relative or absolute path at import statement, but only the name of the file to include. In my case:

```
<import namespace="..." schemaLocation="a.xsd"/>
```

To do this, i've added a link to the original file at the .project so that both files seem to be next to each other.
The problem now is the error

```
src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'a:Some' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
```

if I reference a type Some from a.xsd.

Is there a fix to not get this error or is this a bug in the editor?

If I type "a:" at the editor it proposes me type Some and if I hit F3 at a:Some the file a.xsd is opened and type Some is marked. So the link is recognized...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid using either a relative or an absolute path in the schemaLocation attribute:  the attribute takes a URI, and all URIs are either absolute or relative.  The one you show (`a.xsd`) is relative.

Some HTTP servers avoid following symbolic links unless you change their configuration; some URI resolution libraries refuse to follow symbolic links when resolving file: URIs.  If I understand correctly, they are trying to protect you from some form of cross-site scripting.  Looks as if you're being bitten by this caution on their part.  You might try hard links, or there may be a convenient way to change the configuration of the appropriate modules.